How to check if a user is in a specific guild
Hey there,
I'm trying to make a command, that invites a person to a football club. Because, I don't want anyone to join that isn't in the main server, I wanted to check if the user is in the discord.
I've tried countless solutions, but nothing worked. I don't know why, but I hope that someone can help me with this problem.
Here's the code (I highlighted where it will check)
const user = interaction.options.getMember('user');
           const club = interaction.options.getRole('club');
            const position = interaction.options.getString('position');
            const guild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch('1231641406083301458');
            const mainguild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch('1232018031736000613');
            const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(user.id);
            const mainmember = await mainguild.members.fetch(user.id);
            const guildMember = await guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
            


            try {

                const guild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch('1231641406083301458');
            
                if (!member) {
                    const nothere = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor('#fc0317')
                    .setDescription('User not found.')
                    await interaction.reply({embeds: [nothere], ephemeral: true })
                }
                else if (!guild) {
                    const noguild = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor('#fc0317')
                    .setDescription('Guild not found.')
                    await interaction.reply({embeds: [noguild], ephemeral: true })
                }

                

               ** else if (member.guild.id === guild.id) {
                    const nothere = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor('#fc0317')
                    .setDescription('User not found on the IFF server.')
                    await interaction.reply({embeds: [nothere], ephemeral: true })
                }**

                else if (interaction.member === user) {
                    const nothere = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor('#fc0317')
                    .setDescription(`You can't add yourself to the club!`)
                    await interaction.reply({embeds: [nothere], ephemeral: true })
                }

Aswell, I'm pretty new to discord.js and not very experienced. If someone could show the solution and explain to me, I would be grateful.
Kind regards,
officialdatch
I expected that if the person isn't in the discord specified here:
const guild = await interaction.client.guilds.fetch('1231641406083301458');
it will say, what says here:
const nothere = new EmbedBuilder() .setColor('#fc0317') .setDescription('User not found on the IFF server.') await interaction.reply({embeds: [nothere], ephemeral: true })

Obtaining a guild member object using GuildManager. If member is not in the guild, it will return false.
const guild = interaction.client.guilds.cache.get('1231641406083301458')
if (!guild.members.cache.get(member.id)) {
  // Not Found embed here
};

